# Silverlight: Hiding RadPaneGroup problem

Tags: silverlight, telerik, docking, dockpanel, raddocking

Hi i am facing a very strange problem.

My requirement is to have a tree on the left hand side of a page a view on the right hand side of the page. Clicking various nodes of the tree shows different views.

I have implemented this using two rad pane groups. Now i have implemented all the logic and the tree nodes hide or show the desired RadPaneGroup, so i am going on the right path.

But the problem is that when the page initially loads both Pane Groups are shown. I want to have one initially hidden. The second RadPane Group visibility is collapsed but it still shows up. How do i hide one of the rad pane group initially.

Kind Regards,

```
  <telerik:RadDocking Grid.Row="2" AllowUnsafeMode="True"  BorderThickness="0" Background="#F2F2F3" HasDocumentHost="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="radDocking1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
                <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="FloatingDockable">
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup Background="#F2F2F3" Name="redemptionAssignmentViewPaneGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" telerik:ProportionalStackPanel.RelativeSize="400, 200" >
                        <telerik:RadPane  Header="Assignment View" CanUserClose="False">
                        </telerik:RadPane>
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                    <telerik:RadPaneGroup Visibility="Collapsed" Background="#F2F2F3" Name="redemptionBacthViewPaneGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" telerik:ProportionalStackPanel.RelativeSize="400, 200" BackgroundVisibility="Collapsed">
                        <telerik:RadPane  Header="Assignment View" CanUserClose="False">
                        </telerik:RadPane>
                        <telerik:RadPane  Header="Assignment View" CanUserClose="False">
                        </telerik:RadPane>
                    </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
            </telerik:RadDocking.DocumentHost>
            <telerik:RadSplitContainer InitialPosition="DockedLeft" Width="210">
                <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
                    <telerik:RadPane Header="Redemption Center Center" CanDockInDocumentHost="True" CanUserClose="False" PaneHeaderVisibility="Visible">
                        <my:RedemptionTreeView VerticalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="redemptionTree"/>
                    </telerik:RadPane>
                </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
            </telerik:RadSplitContainer>
        </telerik:RadDocking>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Telerik said :

> The RadPaneGroup control changes its
>   Visibility property automatically when
>   its visible panes vary. If you want to
>   make a RadPaneGroup invisible you just
>   need to make all its panes hidden (to
>   set their IsHidden property to true).
>   **As the RadPaneGroup uses its
>   Visibility property internally you
>   shouldn't change it yourself.**

[RadPanelGroup and Visibility collapsed not working](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/docking/radpanelgroup-and-visibility-collapsed-not-working.aspx)

So you need to hide each of the RadPane in the RadPaneGroup to hide the RadPaneGroup :

```
<telerik:RadPaneGroup Background="#F2F2F3" Name="redemptionBacthViewPaneGroup" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" telerik:ProportionalStackPanel.RelativeSize="400, 200" BackgroundVisibility="Collapsed">
    <telerik:RadPane IsHidden="True" Header="Assignment View" CanUserClose="False">
    </telerik:RadPane>
    <telerik:RadPane IsHidden="True" Header="Assignment View" CanUserClose="False">
    </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadPaneGroup>
```

You could also do code behind :

```
myRadPaneGroup.HideAllPanes();
```

[Hiding All Panes Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/silverlight/raddocking-features-pane-groups.html#Hiding_All_Panes)